# powershell: gc -wait issue

Tags: powershell, virtualization

Running Hercules to emulate a mainframe on two PCs—yes, geek alert, I know—one running Windows 7, one recently upgraded to 10.

Hercules emulates the mainframe's printers by writing to text files, one for each printer. I use `gc -wait` to tail the text files to see the output as it happens.

This worked fine under XP years ago, works fine under 10, but not under 7. When I do it under 7:

1. I don't see the file size increment unless I kill the tail
2. the tail doesn't see new data appended to the file unless I kill the tail and restart.

I have seen the tail process get the new data when I brought up explorer and clicked on the containing folder in the navigation pane, but I have not been able to reproduce that behavior. `gc -wait` correctly tails other things, both other powershell applets and Win32 apps. I have no idea what's different about Hercules and why it behaves fine under 10. The Windows 7 machine has PowerShell 4 installed. I'm not sure about the Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly including the `-tail x` parameter?  `gc $file -tail 10 -wait`.  Windows 10 comes with PS v4.  Are both machines 64 bit OS?

Comment: Yep, I did try that. No go. Yes, they are both 64-bit. It's odd. Just to see, I downloaded unxutils and copied tail.exe out of it and it works fine in all cases. So, I have a work around for the problem, but it's disconcerting that powershell has made something so basic unreliable.

Comment: Watching log files is not actually a common windows admin task.  For event logs, if you need to see it updating, you use the gui and refresh.  It's typically the posix turned windows admins who want to use tail.  And thus comes the unixuitils package.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm actually tailing the print output of my virtual mainframe. Standing in the data center watching the print roll out. Hehe... It's actually pretty neat seeing MVS booted up on a PC looking exactly like it did when I was in school 35 years ago. Before Windows took over my world, I was a VAX/VMS admin who always wondered what the mainframe world was like. Now I know, at least a little bit. :) Cheers.